# Connect nodes with arc and arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE: I am trying to connect the nodes `C`, `A`, `S` and `T` with arcs and arrow heads. I am able to connect them with straight lines but reading through some documentation here I am still unable to do it. I have drawn a circle that should show the path I am look to get but with arrow in an anti-clockwise direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,cap=round,>=latex]
        \draw[->] (-1.125cm,0cm) -- (1.125cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.125cm) -- (0cm,1.125cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
            \foreach \x/\xtext/\xcoordinate in {
                45/QI/{(x>0,y>0)}, 
                135/QII/{(x<0,y>0)}, 
                225/QIII/{(x<0,y<0)}, 
                315/QIV/{(x>0,y<0)}} 
                {%
                    \draw (\x:0.65cm) node[fill=white,text width=2.5cm,align=center]
                    {\xtext \\ $\xcoordinate$};
                }
            \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(0.3cm);
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {
                45/A, 
                135/S, 
                225/T, 
                315/C} 
                {%
                    \draw (\y:0.3cm) node[shape=circle,fill=white,text width=1cm,align=center,font=\bfseries\large,text=black,inner sep=0pt]
                    {\ytext}coordinate (\ytext);
                }
            \draw[-latex,shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt] (S) -- (T);
            \draw[-latex,shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt] (A) -- (S);
            \draw[-latex,shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt] (C) -- (A);
            \draw[-latex,shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt] (T) -- (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I have so far:

[image]

My closest attempt is to use:

```
\draw[shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt,bend right,->]  (C) to (A);
\draw[shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt,bend right,->]  (A) to (S);
\draw[shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt,bend right,->]  (S) to (T);
\draw[shorten <= 10pt,shorten >= 10pt,bend right,->]  (T) to (C);
```

This is what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78318/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287284/drawing-a-diagram-of-a-three-cycle/287354#287354

Comment: @jsbibra I read those and still looking at the code. Am looking for a solution that applies to my question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417283/special-smartdiagram-tikz-process-diagram/417298#417298

Comment: Eduardo Alves da Silva has given a solution--does it suit you or is there something else required? please give a hand sketch of the output required

Comment: @jsbibra See updated question with desired result.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287293/197451  ---this should match   or            https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287319/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415841/197451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me recycle [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512539) and adjust it to your settings. The [problem is always the same: connect nodes on a circular arc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511183). One answer is to construct an actual circle, and compute the intersections with the node boundary. Luckily you have already taken them to be circle shapes, so all that really was to do is to name the paths, that is, to add the key `name path=\ytext` to the circular nodes. (BTW, you can name the nodes, there is no need to add extra coordinates.) This yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending,calc,intersections}
\tikzset{pics/circular arc/.style args={from #1 to #2}{code={
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circular arc/##1}} 
  \path[name path=arc,draw=none] 
   let \p1=(#1),\p2=(#2),\n1={Mod(720+atan2(\y1,\x1),360)},
   \n2={Mod(720+atan2(\y2,\x2),360)},
     \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2+360)}
   in    (\n1:\pv{r}) arc(\n1:\n3:\pv{r});
 \draw[pic actions,
    name intersections={of=#1 and arc,by=arcstart},
    name intersections={of=#2 and arc,by=arcend}] 
    let \p1=(arcstart),\p2=(arcend),\n1={Mod(720+atan2(\y1,\x1),360)},
     \n2={Mod(720+atan2(\y2,\x2),360)},
     \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2+360)}
  in (\n1:\pv{r}) arc(\n1:\n3:\pv{r});
 }},circular arc/.cd,r/.initial=0.3cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line cap=round,>=latex]
        \draw[->] (-1.125cm,0cm) -- (1.125cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.125cm) -- (0cm,1.125cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
            \foreach \x/\xtext/\xcoordinate in {
                45/QI/{(x>0,y>0)}, 
                135/QII/{(x<0,y>0)}, 
                225/QIII/{(x<0,y<0)}, 
                315/QIV/{(x>0,y<0)}} 
                {%
                    \draw (\x:0.65cm) node[fill=white,text width=2.5cm,align=center]
                    {\xtext \\ $\xcoordinate$};
                }
            \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(0.3cm);
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {
                45/A, 
                135/S, 
                225/T, 
                315/C} 
                {%
                    \draw (\y:0.3cm) 
                    node[shape=circle,name path=\ytext,
                    fill=white,text width=1cm,align=center,
                    font=\bfseries\large,text=black,inner sep=0pt]
                    (\ytext){\ytext};
                }
            \path[shorten >=-2pt,-{Latex[bend]},transform shape] pic{circular arc=from S to T}
             pic{circular arc=from T to C} 
             pic{circular arc=from C to A}
              pic{circular arc=from A to S};
            %\draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) circle[radius=0.3cm];  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment the line

```
\draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) circle[radius=0.3cm];
```

you get

[image]

showing that the arcs really follow a circle.

If you replace `text width=1cm` by `text width=1.75em`, you get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending,calc,intersections}
\tikzset{pics/circular arc/.style args={from #1 to #2}{code={
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circular arc/##1}} 
  \path[name path=arc,draw=none] 
   let \p1=(#1),\p2=(#2),\n1={Mod(720+atan2(\y1,\x1),360)},
   \n2={Mod(720+atan2(\y2,\x2),360)},
     \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2+360)}
   in    (\n1:\pv{r}) arc(\n1:\n3:\pv{r});
 \draw[pic actions,
    name intersections={of=#1 and arc,by=arcstart},
    name intersections={of=#2 and arc,by=arcend}] 
    let \p1=(arcstart),\p2=(arcend),\n1={Mod(720+atan2(\y1,\x1),360)},
     \n2={Mod(720+atan2(\y2,\x2),360)},
     \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2+360)}
  in (\n1:\pv{r}) arc(\n1:\n3:\pv{r});
 }},circular arc/.cd,r/.initial=0.3cm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line cap=round,>=latex]
        \draw[->] (-1.125cm,0cm) -- (1.125cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.125cm) -- (0cm,1.125cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
            \foreach \x/\xtext/\xcoordinate in {
                45/QI/{(x>0,y>0)}, 
                135/QII/{(x<0,y>0)}, 
                225/QIII/{(x<0,y<0)}, 
                315/QIV/{(x>0,y<0)}} 
                {%
                    \draw (\x:0.65cm) node[fill=white,text width=2.5cm,align=center]
                    {\xtext \\ $\xcoordinate$};
                }
            \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(0.3cm);
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {
                45/A, 
                135/S, 
                225/T, 
                315/C} 
                {%
                    \draw (\y:0.3cm) 
                    node[shape=circle,name path global=\ytext,
                    fill=white,text width=1.75em,align=center,
                    font=\bfseries\large,text=black,inner sep=0pt]
                    (\ytext){\ytext};
                }
            \path[shorten >=-2pt,-{Latex[bend]},transform shape] pic{circular arc=from S to T}
             pic{circular arc=from T to C} 
             pic{circular arc=from C to A}
              pic{circular arc=from A to S};
            %\draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) circle[radius=0.3cm];  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code also uses `name path global` instead of `name path`. (On my updated TeXLive 2019 installation I do not need `global`.)

Finally, if all the nodes have really the same size, you can just use simple arcs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line cap=round,>=latex]
        \draw[->] (-1.125cm,0cm) -- (1.125cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.125cm) -- (0cm,1.125cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
            \foreach \x/\xtext/\xcoordinate in {
                45/QI/{(x>0,y>0)}, 
                135/QII/{(x<0,y>0)}, 
                225/QIII/{(x<0,y<0)}, 
                315/QIV/{(x>0,y<0)}} 
                {%
                    \draw (\x:0.65cm) node[fill=white,text width=2.5cm,align=center]
                    {\xtext \\ $\xcoordinate$};
                }
            \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(0.3cm);
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {
                45/A, 
                135/S, 
                225/T, 
                315/C} 
                {%
                    \draw (\y:0.3cm) 
                    node[shape=circle,
                    fill=white,text width=1.75em,align=center,
                    font=\bfseries\large,text=black,inner sep=0pt]
                    (\ytext){\ytext};
                }
            \foreach \X in {0,...,3} 
            {\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (\X*90-30:0.3cm) arc(\X*90-30:\X*90+30:0.3cm);}
            %\draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) circle[radius=0.3cm];  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the value `30` to your needs to make the arrows longer or shorter. This works fine but the arrows do not adjust their length to the size of the nodes. In you setting with fixed `text width` you prevent nodes from growing, so this solution should be OK.

Comment: For some reason or the other it does not compile for me.

Comment: @azetina What is the error message that you get? (I have a very up-to-date TeXLive2019 installation, maybe you need to update your installation.)

Comment: https://imgur.com/bFmJDEe

Comment: @azetina Did you copy the full code? The key `name path=\ytext,` in the nodes is essential. This is what I meant by "was to do is to name the paths".

Comment: I copied your full code and compiled as is.

Comment: @azetina It complains that it does not know the paths. Could you try to replace `name path=\ytext,` by `name path global=\ytext,`? I added an explicit code that has this key at the bottom.

Comment: @azetina I added a version that does not rely on intersections. (Still surprised you get errors, but it is hard to debug this.)

Comment: I updated `texlive`. Works fine now! Thanks. Lovely solution. Am learning a lot.

Comment: In principle one can use the formula `myalpha(\r,\R)=atan(\r*sqrt(-\r*\r+4*\R*\R)/(\r*\r-2*\R*\R);` to solve the problem analytically. alpha is the difference between the angle of the center of the node and the angle where the arrow attaches at the node. For instance, `\path[draw=red] let \p1=($(S.north)-(S.center)$),\p2=($(S.center)-(0,0)$),
    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x2,\y2)},
    \n3={45+myalpha(\n1,\n2)} in 
    (\n3:\n2) arc(\n3:-\n3:\n2);` draws the arc between S and A.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way of doing this is using the angles package. See if the following is what you want or not:

Edit: created "auxiliar" nodes `C2`, `A2` , `S2`and `T2`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,cap=round,>=latex]
        \draw[->] (-1.125cm,0cm) -- (1.125cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.125cm) -- (0cm,1.125cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
            \foreach \x/\xtext/\xcoordinate in {
                45/QI/{(x>0,y>0)}, 
                135/QII/{(x<0,y>0)}, 
                225/QIII/{(x<0,y<0)}, 
                315/QIV/{(x>0,y<0)}} 
                {%
                    \draw (\x:0.65cm) node[fill=white,text width=2.5cm,align=center]
                    {\xtext \\ $\xcoordinate$};
                }

            \foreach \y/\ytext in {
                45/A, 
                135/S, 
                225/T, 
                315/C} 
                {%
                    \draw (\y:0.3cm) node[]
                    {\ytext}coordinate (\ytext);
                }
            \node[] at (0cm,0cm) (O) {};
            \node[] at ([yshift=1, xshift=1]S) (S2) {};
            \node[] at ([yshift=-1, xshift=1]A) (A2) {};
            \node[] at ([yshift=1,xshift=-1]T) (T2) {};
            \node[] at ([xshift=-1]C) (C2) {};

            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=1.5cm] {angle = A--O--S2};
            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=1.5cm] {angle = S--O--T2};
            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=1.5cm] {angle = T--O--C2};
            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=1.5cm] {angle = C--O--A2};


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]